# Can I configure the Kate kde editor to use the same 'Find' string across files?

Tags: kde-plasma, kate

I'm finally getting the hang of the (typically overly complex) Kate editor in KDE.  The only thing I haven't figured out is how to override the default behavior of Kate maintaining a different 'Find' string for each file you have open.  For example, it's really annoying when you are looking at code and want to find a function in another module.  Normally you'd doubleclick the function and then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.  So far so good, it sets up to find the highlighted text.  But then switch to another module open in another tab, and hit <kbd>F3</kbd>.  You get the expected 'Find Next' behavior, but the text it looks for is whatever you looked for last in *that* module.  Not the text you just asked to find.

I can see how it might be a nice *option* to maintain separate 'Find' strings for each module, but seriously - as the default?  And I can't find any way to change how this works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that allows extended search in multiple files. I think you can also re-assign keyboard shortcuts to use this instead of the simple search.

**Settings menu > Configure Kate > Plugins > Search & Replace**

Comment: I have that plugin enabled.  Yes, it lets you type in a search term and search for it across open files.  But it does not affect the default 'find' behavior, which is what most people use to do searching - because it's quicker.  You can highlight some text and find will default to that text.  The Search and Replace dialog has its own text input box - which, by the way, is also odd.  Why on earth would the Search plugin not initialize it's text like Find does.  Probably because it's a plugin.  This should be built in behavior that 'just works' like in just about every other Programmer's editor.